# AWK: How to create an array of dates of the last days?

Tags: arrays, awk, date-arithmetic

I have CSV file with millions of records. One of the fields  (e.g. $2) contains date. I need the date to be from the last week.

I thought to use AWK to substitute the current date with a random date from the last 7 days. For this, I wanted to **create an array** indexed 1..7 and it's values will be the last 7 dates (e.g. 2013-10-08, 2013-10-07...).

Is there a function which can calculate dates from a given date? Or some code that can do the job?

My timestamp in the file is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".

#### Update - answer

This what fitted my needs at last:

```awk
BEGIN { srand() } 
{ 
  split($2, a, "-") 
  t  = mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " substr(a[3], 1, 2) " 00 00 00") 
  $2 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", t - int(7*rand()+1) * 3600 * 24 + int(3600*24*rand())) 
}
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have something like this:

```
data1,2013-10-04,data2,...
```

and you want to change the second column date to a random day in the past 7 days.

This is fairly straightforward with GNU awk where you have the `mktime` and `strftime` commands.

Here is a gawk script (**rnd_date.awk**) that works on the input listed above:

```awk
BEGIN { srand() }
{
  split($2, a, /-/)
  t  = mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3] " 00 00 00")
  $2 = strftime("%F", t - int(7*rand()+1) * 3600 * 24)
}
1
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f rnd_date.awk FS=, OFS=, infile
```

Example output:

```
data1,2013-09-29,data2,...
```

There are a couple of caveats:

1. `srand` seeds the pseudo-random number generator with "seconds since the epoch", so if you rapidly invoke this script there will be no randomness between each invocation. You can counter this be supplying a better seed, e.g. with GNU date:

   `awk -f rnd_date -v s=$(date +%N) 'BEGIN { srand(s) } ...'`
2. Setting `$2` will force a reformatting of the whole line, depending on your data format this may or may not be a problem.

#### Edit

I see, your data is differently formatted, you have:

```
data1,2013-10-04 01:01:01,data2,...
```

You can adapt the above like this (with better named variables):

```awk
BEGIN { srand() }
{
  split($2, date, /-| |:/)
  since_epoch = mktime(date[1] " " date[2] " " date[3] " " date[4] " " date[5] " " date[6])
  $2 = strftime("%F %T", since_epoch - int(7*rand()+1) * 3600 * 24)
}
1
```

Or if you do not care about the `HH:MM:SS` part

```
BEGIN { srand() }
{
  split($2, a, /-| /)
  t  = mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3] " 00 00 00")
  $2 = strftime("%F %T", t - int(7*rand()+1) * 3600 * 24)
}
1
```

Example output:

```
data1,2013-09-27 00:00:00,data2,...
```

Comment: My timestamp in the file is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".
This what fitted my needs at last:
BEGIN { srand() }
{
  split($2, a, "-")
   t  = mktime(a[1]" "a[2]" "substr(a[3],1,2)" 00 00 00")
  $2 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", t - int(7*rand()+1) * 3600 * 24 + int(3600*24*rand()))
}
1

Comment: @usulkies: You should add this information as an edit to your question. See my edit above for an alternative approach to your solution. Also, if your question has been answered consider accepting the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some like this `awk`

```
awk '$2>=from && $2<=to' from="$(date +%b" "%e" "%H:%M:%S -d -7days)" to="$(date +%b" "%e" "%H:%M:%S)" file
```

You need to tune the `date` command to give same output as the date in field `$2` that contains the date.  Then this will give you the last 7 days of data